# Tool for editing .IL files?

Tags: .net, disassembly, il, intermediate-language

Currently I use Notepad for this purpose. Is there any specific tool intended for editing .NET Intermediate Language files?

Dotnet IL Editor (DILE) disassembles files before editing them, I don't need that functionality - only actual editing is needed in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [ReflexIL](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/) very helpful. Check out [my post](http://blog.vijay.name/post/Digging-into-old-components-through-MSIL.aspx) on the same for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **dnSpy**. It's an open-source project on GitHub and appears to be well-known since it has >2,000 stars. (Note: I haven't tried it myself yet, but am planning to in the very near future.) https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy